# Tkinter button not calling a file in python

Tags: python, tkinter, pygame

```
from tkinter import*
from pygame.locals import *
from random import randint
import pygame
import time
from snake2electricboogaloo import snake_electric_boogaloo

window = Tk()
window.title("Snake 2 Launcher")
window.geometry('600x600')

def callback():
    snake_electric_boogaloo()

B = Button(window, text ="Run Game", justify=CENTER, command = callback)
B.place(x = 50,y=50)

window.mainloop()
```

This code is not calling the game, this is for a school project, I have spent way too much time working on this.  The names are all correct and the game is in the same file as the GUI.

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Have you tried using a debugger, or putting in print statements inside `callback` and inside `snake_electric_boogaloo` to verify that they are or aren't being called? What happens if you remove all of the tkinter code and just have `snake_electric_boogaloo()` at the bottom of the file?

Answer (score 0):

I can't help you too much because I don't know your code for snake_electric_boogaloo, but I can tell you that when calling a callback from a button or key in tkinter, you must add an extra parameter to the function. You need to **replace `def callback():` with `def callback(event):`**
Your edited code should look something like:

```
from tkinter import*
from pygame.locals import *
from random import randint
import pygame
import time
from snake2electricboogaloo import snake_electric_boogaloo

window = Tk()
window.title("Snake 2 Launcher")
window.geometry('600x600')

def callback(event):
    snake_electric_boogaloo()

B = Button(window, text ="Run Game", justify=CENTER, command = callback)
B.place(x = 50,y=50)

window.mainloop()
```

I hope this was helpful!